# Bluetooth device is missing in Windows 10 but USB keeps disconnecting

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, hp-elitebook

I have a HP Elitebook 850 G5 which repeatedly plays the disconnect/connect sounds. This started some time ago - maybe after a system update. I tried to find the cause for this behaviour and found the device ID to be USB\VID_8087. The HP support forum suggests to install the intel Bluetooth driver - which I did. But it did not solve the problem. Further investigation showed, that the whole Bluetooth branch is missing from the device manager.

I tried uninstalling the Intel drivers and even deleting the USB Devices but none of which solved the problem. Any ideas how to restore Bluetooth functionality?

Comment: Find the HP Driver Update App, download that, install it and run it. See if it can repair your drivers.  See if it finds hardware errors.  If there are no errors, you may need to back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: Thank you for this input. I will see if the HP App can do any good.

Comment: The HP Driver App did not solve the problem. I just did a clean install of Windows 10 (current image from Microsoft) and the problem persists. Windows just does not recognize any Bluetooth adapter. I even tried replacing the Intel 8265 WIFI Adapter with one of the same type and a different one (Killer WIFI) but bluetooth still does not appear in device manager. There is no unknown device but there is a Serial USB Device (COM3) which is connected to the Intel XMM7360-P WWAN.

Comment: It is probably time to take the computer to a local repair shop and get an estimate to repair it.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have found a workaround. After removing the LTE Module (Fibocom L850-GL) everything is working fine now (except the LTE connection of course, which i do not need currently).